# Why does setting up FontAwesome with SVG Core disable these options by default?

Tags: svg, font-awesome, webfonts, font-awesome-6

I'm trying to make my [FontAwesome 6](https://fontawesome.com/v6) installation more lightweight by importing the few individual icons I'm using instead of a whole style, via my web app's `npm` build process. The documentation [seems to say](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/get-started) that the way to do this is by installing `@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core` (and then presumably an icon pack like `@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons`, although not explicitly mentioned in the docs).

Using FontAwesome in this way **disables by default** the following capabilities of the standard FontAwesome configuration:

> - Automatically replaces `<i>` tags with `<svg>`
> - Watches the page for icon changes and additions

Going deeper into this, [another section of the docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/apis/javascript/configuration#options) shows that the specific options disabled are `autoReplaceSvg` and `observeMutations`.

What are the reason(s) that configuring FontAwesome in this way disables these options by default, and is there any disadvantage to re-enabling them, either performance or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

A day or so later, I found this by chance in [another section](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/dig-deeper/svg-core) of the (very extensive) documentation:

> Our Basic packages (@fortawesome/fontawesome-free and
> @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro) are aimed at individuals who would like
> to quickly integrate Font Awesome into their projects but do not want
> to invest the time and effort to understand what's going on under the
> hood. For this reason a lot of the behavior is automatic and works
> without any intervention.
>
> In contrast, the fontawesome-svg-core package is for more specialized
> situations or for forming the underlying API to power other components
> or libraries. In fact, our own official components for Vue, React,
> Ember, and Angular all use the fontawesome-svg-core package under the
> hood.
>
> Because of this **the core package and the icon content packages avoid
> doing anything automatic or creating side-effects that make
> development with them difficult to control or reason.**