# Import only needed Fontawesome Icons with Laravel Mix

Tags: laravel, font-awesome, laravel-mix

i'm using the following Code in my bootstrap.js in Laravel, following the solution: [How to import individual icons with FontAwesome v6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72005729/how-to-import-individual-icons-with-fontawesome-v6)

```
import { library, dom, config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.searchPseudoElements = true;

import { faCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

library.add( faCheck );

dom.i2svg();
dom.watch();
```

But Laravel mix, includes the whole Fontawesome icons, to the app.js.

Have anyone some hints, to push me to the solution?

i'm barely new to work with Laravel Mix and using npm.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in my question that you linked to, to remove the already loaded icons from your project? Note I'm talking about the steps in the question, not the answer.